# is it possbile update JSF componet from cometd listener of backing Bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, listener, javabeans, cometd

Is the cometd listener able to invoke the "RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()" ?

sayHello() can work but addRow() is not working.

It seems RequestContext can not get the Current Instance or am I on the incorrect way?
(org.primefaces.context.RequestContext)

Thank you.

Here is Output:

> Bean received Msg : 2
>
> ready to getCurrentInstance
>
> org.cometd.bayeux.client.ClientSession - Exception while invoking
>   listener bean.AlarmBean$NodeLsnr@7e33d20f
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   bean.AlarmBean.addRow(AlarmBean.java:48)  at
>   bean.AlarmBean$NodeLsnr.onMessage(AlarmBean.java:57)  at
>
> > org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession$AbstractSessionChannel.notifyOnMessage(AbstractClientSession.java:432)

Code:

```
@Named("AlarmBean")
@ViewScoped
public class AlarmBean implements Serializable {

private String defaultURL = "http://localhost:31360/topoServer/cometd/foo";
private BayeuxClient client;
private static final String NODE_CHANNEL = "/node";
private NodeLsnr NL = new NodeLsnr();
private int i = 1;

@PostConstruct
public void initComted(){
    initClient();
}

public void sayHello() {
    i++;
    System.out.println("Bean received Msg : " + Integer.toString(i));
}

public void addRow() {          
    System.out.println("ready to getCurrentInstance");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("f1:table1");
}

private class NodeLsnr implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel csc, Message msg) {
        System.out.println("data received ");
        sayHello();
        addRow();
    }
}

public void initClient() {
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    try {
        httpClient.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {           
        return;
    }

    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    ClientTransport longPool = LongPollingTransport.create(options, httpClient);
    client = new BayeuxClient(defaultURL, longPool);
    client.handshake();
    boolean handshaken = client.waitFor(10000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);
    if (handshaken) {
        System.out.println("connected ok");
        client.getChannel("/node").subscribe(NL);
        System.out.println("subscribe to /node channel.");
    }

}
```

}